# Arm resets position when exported?

Tags: export, rigging, external-applications, unity

So in edit mode when I export my hand model into unity 3d, the hand resets its position, but when I go into edit mode the hand also goes back to its original position. I have a animation with it, so if I select the armature the hand doesn't animate. Hard to explain.

[image: Hand]

[image: Hand edit mode]

Answer (score 2):

The mesh uses a modifier to deform based on the position of the armature. By default the deformation from the armature is not visible while in edit mode but can be turned on if you want to. The button highlighted in red will show a 'shadowy' version of where the mesh would be based on the armature. The blue highlighted button is only visible if the first one is enabled and when enable the mesh will be shown fully deformed while in edit mode.

[image]

As for Unity - check that you are exporting the action and that Unity is using the action and not just the default pose position.

Comment: How exactly do i export the position

Comment: The default pose position is the position of the bones when no animation data has altered it. If your hand goes back to this position in unity, it could indicate that you aren't exporting the animation data or you aren't enabling the animation in unity. [This short video at unitycookie](http://cgcookie.com/unity/2011/12/05/exporting-characters-from-blender/) may help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm running into the same issue, but it's at least very similar. When I export my model to FBX for Unity, the pose changes in Blender. Then when the object loads into Unity, the default pose is different entirely. What I found in my case was the pose was generated by the selected action for the armature, so when the model was exported it updated the pose accordingly.

Before exporting the model to .fbx move the action to the rest keyframe.